# Problems with Rcpp precision

Tags: c++, r, rounding, precision, rcpp

Consider the following C++ function in R using Rcpp:

```
cppFunction('long double statZn_cpp(NumericVector dat, double kn) {
  double n = dat.size();
  // Get total sum and sum of squares; this will be the "upper sum"
  // (i.e. the sum above k)
  long double s_upper, s_square_upper;
  // The "lower sums" (i.e. those below k)
  long double s_lower, s_square_lower;
  // Get lower sums
  // Go to kn - 1 to prevent double-counting in main
  // loop
  for (int i = 0; i < kn - 1; ++i) {
    s_lower += dat[i];
    s_square_lower += dat[i] * dat[i];
  }
  // Get upper sum
  for (int i = kn - 1; i < n; ++i) {
    s_upper += dat[i];
    s_square_upper += dat[i] * dat[i];
  }
  // The maximum, which will be returned
  long double M = 0;
  // A candidate for the new maximum, used in a loop
  long double M_candidate;

  // Compute the test statistic
  for (int k = kn; k <= (n - kn); ++k) {
    // Update s and s_square for both lower and upper
    s_lower += dat[k-1];
    s_square_lower += dat[k-1] * dat[k-1];
    s_upper -= dat[k-1];
    s_square_upper -= dat[k-1] * dat[k-1];

    // Get estimate of sd for this k
    long double sdk = sqrt((s_square_lower - pow(s_lower, 2.0) / k +
                      s_square_upper -
                      pow(s_upper, 2.0) / (n - k))/n);
    M_candidate = abs(s_lower / k - s_upper / (n - k)) / sdk;
    // Choose new maximum
    if (M_candidate > M) {
      M = M_candidate;
    }
  }

  return M * sqrt(kn);
}')
```

Try the command `statZn_cpp(1:20,4)`, and you will get `6.963106`, which is the correct answer. Scaling should not matter; `statZn_cpp(1:20*10,4)` will also yield the correct answer of 6.963106. But `statZn_cpp(1:20/10,4)` yields the wrong answer of `6.575959`, and `statZn_cpp(1:20/100,4)` again gives you the obviously wrong answer of `0`. More to the point (and relevant to my research, which involves simulation studies), when I try `statZn_cpp(rnorm(20),4)`, the answer is almost always `0`, which is wrong.

Clearly the problem has to do with rounding errors, but I don't know where they are or how to fix them (I am brand new to C++). I've tried to expand precision as much as possible. Is there a way to fix the rounding problem? (An R wrapper function is permissible if I should be attempting what amounts to a preprocessing step, but it needs to be robust, working for general levels of precision.)

**EDIT: Here is some "equivalent" R code:**

```
statZn <- function(dat, kn = function(n) {floor(sqrt(n))}) {
  n = length(dat)
  return(sqrt(kn(n))*max(sapply(
      floor(kn(n)):(n - floor(kn(n))), function(k)
        abs(1/k*sum(dat[1:k]) -
              1/(n-k)*sum(dat[(k+1):n]))/sqrt((sum((dat[1:k] -
               mean(dat[1:k]))^2)+sum((dat[(k+1):n] -
               mean(dat[(k+1):n]))^2))/n))))
}
```

Also, the R code below basically replicates the method that should be used by the C++ code. It is capable of reaching the correct answer.

```
  n = length(dat)
  s_lower = 0
  s_square_lower = 0
  s_upper = 0
  s_square_upper = 0
  for (i in 1:(kn-1)) {
    s_lower = s_lower + dat[i]
    s_square_lower = s_square_lower + dat[i] * dat[i]
  }
  for (i in kn:n) {
    s_upper = s_upper + dat[i]
    s_square_upper = s_square_upper + dat[i] * dat[i]
  }
  M = 0

  for (k in kn:(n-kn)) {
    s_lower = s_lower + dat[k]
    s_square_lower = s_square_lower + dat[k] * dat[k]
    s_upper = s_upper - dat[k]
    s_square_upper = s_square_upper - dat[k] * dat[k]

    sdk = sqrt((s_square_lower - (s_lower)^2/k +
                         s_square_upper -
                         (s_upper)^2/(n-k))/n)
    M_candidate = sqrt(kn) * abs(s_lower / k - s_upper / (n - k)) / sdk

    cat('k', k, '\n',
        "s_lower", s_lower, '\n',
        's_square_lower', s_square_lower, '\n',
        's_upper', s_upper, '\n',
        's_square_upper', s_square_upper, '\n',
        'sdk', sdk, '\n',
        'M_candidate', M_candidate, '\n\n')

    if (M_candidate > M) {
      M = M_candidate
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm actually getting 0 for all of the calls to `statZn_cpp` listed above. What are you using for an operating system, compiler, and compiler version?

Comment: I also get always 0. Can you explain in words what the function should do?

Comment: I am currently using a Linux distro, Lubuntu (another flavor of Ubuntu). My version of R is 3.2.4, and my version of Rcpp is 0.12.3. I presume that Rcpp uses my system compiler, which is g++ v. 5.2.1., though I don't know this for a fact (I never changed it, though).

Comment: There is a test statistic that I am researching and this function is supposed to compute it. It's hard for me to describe in words what this statistic is, but I can provide some R code that is equivalent.

statZn <- function(dat, kn = function(n) {floor(sqrt(n))}) {
n = length(dat);

  return(sqrt(kn(n))*max(sapply(
      floor(kn(n)):(n - floor(kn(n))), function(k)
        abs(1/k*sum(dat[1:k]) -
              1/(n-k)*sum(dat[(k+1):n]))/sqrt((sum((dat[1:k] -
               mean(dat[1:k]))^2)+sum((dat[(k+1):n] -
               mean(dat[(k+1):n]))^2))/n))));
}

Comment: I have added more equivalent code to the main post to help understand the problem. All the additional code obtains the correct answer.

Comment: That function is  very hard to read. All I can say is that I'm pretty sure that is not a rounding problem and you very likely have a bug in the C++ code. Without fully understanding what's going on, it's hard for me to tell where the bug is.

Comment: Let's try this: The function computes a test statistic for change point analysis. First, compute for each k between kn and n - kn the distance (an absolute value) of the means of the two sides of the dataset when split at k. Divide by a modified formula for the standard deviation (called in the code sdk). Next, take the maximum of this. Finally, multiply by the square root of kn. I will add that I am sure this is a rounding problem because I have added R code that is basically R's equivalent of the C++ code, and it works fine.

Comment: A rounding problem doesn't change a 6 into a 0. Your C++ function always returns 0. You seem to know what the function should do and so you are in the best position to spot the bug. Review carefully your code and you'll solve the issue.

Comment: Try adding a debugging step to your loop to monitor the values, [for example](https://gist.github.com/nathan-russell/594151d880e663d41cbb303e717375b4#file-debug-values-cpp). Also, you should always initialize your variables (in C/C++) before first use, e.g. `long double s_upper = 0.0, s_square_upper = 0.0;`, etc. By doing that I was able to get `statZn_cpp(1:20,4)`,
`statZn_cpp(1:20 * 10,4)`, and `statZn_cpp3(1:20 / 10,4)`
(but not the other two examples) to return 6.963106. You might be able to figure out what's happening by using the `printf` code linked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1:** You should not be using `long double`, since R represents all numeric values in the `double` type. Using a more precise type for intermediate calculations is extremely unlikely to provide any benefit, and is more likely to result in strange inconsistencies between platforms.

**2:** You're not initializing `s_upper`, `s_square_upper`, `s_lower`, and `s_square_lower`. (You actually are initializing them in the R implementation, but you forgot in the C++ implementation.)

**3:** Minor point, but I would replace the `pow(x,2.0)` calls with `x*x`. Although this doesn't really matter.

**4:** This is what fixed it for me: You need to qualify calls to C++ standard library functions with their containing namespace. IOW, `std::sqrt()` instead of just `sqrt()`, `std::abs()` instead of just `abs()`, and `std::pow()` instead of just `pow()` if you continue to use it.

---

```
cppFunction('double statZn_cpp(NumericVector dat, double kn) {
  int n = dat.size();
  double s_upper = 0, s_square_upper = 0; // Get total sum and sum of squares; this will be the "upper sum" (i.e. the sum above k)
  double s_lower = 0, s_square_lower = 0; // The "lower sums" (i.e. those below k)
  for (int i = 0; i < kn - 1; ++i) { s_lower += dat[i]; s_square_lower += dat[i] * dat[i]; } // Get lower sums; Go to kn - 1 to prevent double-counting in main
  for (int i = kn - 1; i < n; ++i) { s_upper += dat[i]; s_square_upper += dat[i] * dat[i]; } // Get upper sum
  double M = 0; // The maximum, which will be returned
  double M_candidate; // A candidate for the new maximum, used in a loop
  // Compute the test statistic
  for (int k = kn; k <= (n - kn); ++k) {
    // Update s and s_square for both lower and upper
    s_lower += dat[k-1];
    s_square_lower += dat[k-1] * dat[k-1];
    s_upper -= dat[k-1];
    s_square_upper -= dat[k-1] * dat[k-1];
    // Get estimate of sd for this k
    double sdk = std::sqrt((s_square_lower - s_lower*s_lower / k + s_square_upper - s_upper*s_upper / (n - k))/n);
    M_candidate = std::abs(s_lower / k - s_upper / (n - k)) / sdk;
    if (M_candidate > M) M = M_candidate; // Choose new maximum
  }
  return std::sqrt(kn) * M;
}');

statZn_cpp(1:20,4); ## you will get 6.963106, which is the correct answer
## [1] 6.963106
statZn_cpp(1:20*10,4); ## Scaling should not matter; will also yield the correct answer of 6.963106
## [1] 6.963106
statZn_cpp(1:20/10,4); ## yields the wrong answer of 6.575959
## [1] 6.963106
statZn_cpp(1:20/100,4); ## again gives you the obviously wrong answer of 0.
## [1] 6.963106
set.seed(1L); statZn_cpp(rnorm(20),4); ## More to the point (and relevant to my research, which involves simulation studies), the answer is almost always 0, which is wrong.
## [1] 1.270117
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! Aside from the failure to initialize some variables (I did earlier, but this must have been lost when translating from R to C++), it was probably the lack of namespaces that was the problem. I guess that whatever it is that Rcpp uses by default for those functions should not be trusted.

Comment: @bgoldst you may want to emphasize that `abs()` handles integers and `fabs()` handles doubles. However, `std::abs()` is overloaded and can handle both.

Comment: @Coatless Thanks for your comment. Honestly, I'm not sure exactly what the situation is with respect to the call resolution here. It depends on what names Rcpp exposes and in which namespaces; for example, whether it includes `math.h`/`cmath`/neither, `stdlib.h`/`cstdlib`/neither, possibly which C++ version and compiler is being used, whether Rcpp defines its own wrapper/shim, implicit declarations, etc. This is why I love qualifying function calls with their namespaces; you often don't have to worry about these intricate details. But you're probably right in this case.